# Solve non-linear system of equation in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods, numerical, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to solve non-linear system of equations in Mathemtica.
I tried Solve and NSolve, I also tried to define a_{ij} and b_{ij} and m33=1 numerical to simplify equation, but Mathematica seems to work too long or I doing something wrong.In Mathematica I just trying to find solution, but I also need some c/c++ lib to do this in my code.

Main equation in "operators":

```
M[A[(x,y)]]=B[M[(x,y)]]
```

where "operator" is perspective transform:

```
u= (m13 + m11*x + m12*y)/(m33 + m31*x + m32*y); 

v= (m23 + m21*x +m22*y)/(m33 + m31*x + m32*y);
```

My input in Mathematica:

```
Solve[(b13 + (b11 (m13 + m11 x1 + m12 y1))/(m33 + m31 x1 + 
         m32 y1) + (b12 (m23 + m21 x1 + m22 y1))/(m33 + m31 x1 + 
         m32 y1))/(b33 + (b31 (m13 + m11 x1 + m12 y1))/(m33 + m31 x1 +
          m32 y1) + (b32 (m23 + m21 x1 + m22 y1))/(m33 + m31 x1 + 
         m32 y1)) == (m13 + (m11 (a13 + a11 x1 + a12 y1))/(a33 + 
         a31 x1 + a32 y1) + (m12 (a23 + a21 x1 + a22 y1))/(a33 + 
         a31 x1 + a32 y1))/(m33 + (m31 (a13 + a11 x1 + a12 y1))/(a33 +
          a31 x1 + a32 y1) + (m32 (a23 + a21 x1 + a22 y1))/(a33 + 
         a31 x1 + 
         a32 y1)) && (b23 + (b21 (m13 + m11 x1 + m12 y1))/(m33 + 
         m31 x1 + m32 y1) + (b22 (m23 + m21 x1 + m22 y1))/(m33 + 
         m31 x1 + m32 y1))/(b33 + (b31 (m13 + m11 x1 + m12 y1))/(m33 +
          m31 x1 + m32 y1) + (b32 (m23 + m21 x1 + m22 y1))/(m33 + 
         m31 x1 + 
         m32 y1)) == (m23 + (m21 (a13 + a11 x1 + a12 y1))/(a33 + 
         a31 x1 + a32 y1) + (m22 (a23 + a21 x1 + a22 y1))/(a33 + 
         a31 x1 + a32 y1))/(m33 + (m31 (a13 + a11 x1 + a12 y1))/(a33 +
          a31 x1 + a32 y1) + (m32 (a23 + a21 x1 + a22 y1))/(a33 + 
         a31 x1 + 
         a32 y1)) && (b13 + (b11 (m13 + m11 x2 + m12 y2))/(m33 + 
         m31 x2 + m32 y2) + (b12 (m23 + m21 x2 + m22 y2))/(m33 + 
         m31 x2 + m32 y2))/(b33 + (b31 (m13 + m11 x2 + m12 y2))/(m33 +
          m31 x2 + m32 y2) + (b32 (m23 + m21 x2 + m22 y2))/(m33 + 
         m31 x2 + 
         m32 y2)) == (m13 + (m11 (a13 + a11 x2 + a12 y2))/(a33 + 
         a31 x2 + a32 y2) + (m12 (a23 + a21 x2 + a22 y2))/(a33 + 
         a31 x2 + a32 y2))/(m33 + (m31 (a13 + a11 x2 + a12 y2))/(a33 +
          a31 x2 + a32 y2) + (m32 (a23 + a21 x2 + a22 y2))/(a33 + 
         a31 x2 + 
         a32 y2)) && (b23 + (b21 (m13 + m11 x2 + m12 y2))/(m33 + 
         m31 x2 + m32 y2) + (b22 (m23 + m21 x2 + m22 y2))/(m33 + 
         m31 x2 + m32 y2))/(b33 + (b31 (m13 + m11 x2 + m12 y2))/(m33 +
          m31 x2 + m32 y2) + (b32 (m23 + m21 x2 + m22 y2))/(m33 + 
         m31 x2 + 
         m32 y2)) == (m23 + (m21 (a13 + a11 x2 + a12 y2))/(a33 + 
         a31 x2 + a32 y2) + (m22 (a23 + a21 x2 + a22 y2))/(a33 + 
         a31 x2 + a32 y2))/(m33 + (m31 (a13 + a11 x2 + a12 y2))/(a33 +
          a31 x2 + a32 y2) + (m32 (a23 + a21 x2 + a22 y2))/(a33 + 
         a31 x2 + 
         a32 y2)) && (b13 + (b11 (m13 + m11 x3 + m12 y3))/(m33 + 
         m31 x3 + m32 y3) + (b12 (m23 + m21 x3 + m22 y3))/(m33 + 
         m31 x3 + m32 y3))/(b33 + (b31 (m13 + m11 x3 + m12 y3))/(m33 +
          m31 x3 + m32 y3) + (b32 (m23 + m21 x3 + m22 y3))/(m33 + 
         m31 x3 + 
         m32 y3)) == (m13 + (m11 (a13 + a11 x3 + a12 y3))/(a33 + 
         a31 x3 + a32 y3) + (m12 (a23 + a21 x3 + a22 y3))/(a33 + 
         a31 x3 + a32 y3))/(m33 + (m31 (a13 + a11 x3 + a12 y3))/(a33 +
          a31 x3 + a32 y3) + (m32 (a23 + a21 x3 + a22 y3))/(a33 + 
         a31 x3 + 
         a32 y3)) && (b23 + (b21 (m13 + m11 x3 + m12 y3))/(m33 + 
         m31 x3 + m32 y3) + (b22 (m23 + m21 x3 + m22 y3))/(m33 + 
         m31 x3 + m32 y3))/(b33 + (b31 (m13 + m11 x3 + m12 y3))/(m33 +
          m31 x3 + m32 y3) + (b32 (m23 + m21 x3 + m22 y3))/(m33 + 
         m31 x3 + 
         m32 y3)) == (m23 + (m21 (a13 + a11 x3 + a12 y3))/(a33 + 
         a31 x3 + a32 y3) + (m22 (a23 + a21 x3 + a22 y3))/(a33 + 
         a31 x3 + a32 y3))/(m33 + (m31 (a13 + a11 x3 + a12 y3))/(a33 +
          a31 x3 + a32 y3) + (m32 (a23 + a21 x3 + a22 y3))/(a33 + 
         a31 x3 + 
         a32 y3)) && (b13 + (b11 (m13 + m11 x4 + m12 y4))/(m33 + 
         m31 x4 + m32 y4) + (b12 (m23 + m21 x4 + m22 y4))/(m33 + 
         m31 x4 + m32 y4))/(b33 + (b31 (m13 + m11 x4 + m12 y4))/(m33 +
          m31 x4 + m32 y4) + (b32 (m23 + m21 x4 + m22 y4))/(m33 + 
         m31 x4 + 
         m32 y4)) == (m13 + (m11 (a13 + a11 x4 + a12 y4))/(a33 + 
         a31 x4 + a32 y4) + (m12 (a23 + a21 x4 + a22 y4))/(a33 + 
         a31 x4 + a32 y4))/(m33 + (m31 (a13 + a11 x4 + a12 y4))/(a33 +
          a31 x4 + a32 y4) + (m32 (a23 + a21 x4 + a22 y4))/(a33 + 
         a31 x4 + 
         a32 y4)) && (b23 + (b21 (m13 + m11 x4 + m12 y4))/(m33 + 
         m31 x4 + m32 y4) + (b22 (m23 + m21 x4 + m22 y4))/(m33 + 
         m31 x4 + m32 y4))/(b33 + (b31 (m13 + m11 x4 + m12 y4))/(m33 +
          m31 x4 + m32 y4) + (b32 (m23 + m21 x4 + m22 y4))/(m33 + 
         m31 x4 + 
         m32 y4)) == (m23 + (m21 (a13 + a11 x4 + a12 y4))/(a33 + 
         a31 x4 + a32 y4) + (m22 (a23 + a21 x4 + a22 y4))/(a33 + 
         a31 x4 + a32 y4))/(m33 + (m31 (a13 + a11 x4 + a12 y4))/(a33 +
          a31 x4 + a32 y4) + (m32 (a23 + a21 x4 + a22 y4))/(a33 + 
         a31 x4 + a32 y4)) && m33 == 1, {m11, m12, m13, m21, m22, m23,
   m31, m32}]
```

Comment: You're using a program to generate that Mathematica input, right? ;)

Comment: I do substitutions with Mathematica to get two equations and then copy-paste it 4 times to get 8 equations for 4 points (x1,y1),...,(x4,y4).

Comment: @mrgloom Could you please clarify where are `u,v` entering the top equation ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks u,v just result of operation, for example (u,v)=A[(x,y)] and then we substitut (u,v) into M and get M[(u,v)]. A,B,M are the same operators, just different constants a(ij),b(ij),m(ij).

Comment: It appears to be overdetermined: 9 eqns, 8 unknowns. Not surprisingly, a random substitution for a11 et al gives an empty solution set.

Comment: Okay, I guess m33 was intended to be a variable, so it is not overdetermined.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mathematica and there is a specific StackExchange site for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have any chance with this you will need actual numbers in place of the parameter variables. Otherwise the system is too big to handle.

To illustrate, I created polynomials (ignoring denominator vanishing scenarios) and then did random numeric substitutions for the parameters. I could have eliminated m33 via replacement but opted to leave m33-1==0 in the system. That way no special handling was needed for any one equation. One might for efficiency consider doing such elimination on equation subsets that are linear in their variables.

```
In[40]:= exprs = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}];
e2 = Together[exprs];
polys = Numerator[e2];

In[62]:= allvars = Variables[polys];
vars = {m11, m12, m13, m21, m22, m23, m31, m32, m33};
params = Complement[allvars, vars]

Out[64]= {a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23, a31, a32, a33, b11, b12, b13, \
b21, b22, b23, b31, b32, b33, x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4}

In[69]:= SeedRandom[11111];
substitutions = 
  Thread[params -> RandomInteger[{-1000, 1000}, Length[params]]];

In[71]:= numpolys = polys /. substitutions;
```

NSolve decided that the system was actually underdetermined, that is, your equations have a redundancy (algebraic dependence, to put it more technically). So it intersected with a pseudorandom hyperplane and then got a finite solution set.

```
In[73]:= Timing[solns = NSolve[numpolys == 0, vars];]

During evaluation of In[73]:= NSolve::infsolns: Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1. Returning intersection of solutions with (107814 m11)/118505-(177066 m12)/118505-(164294 m13)/118505+(32943 m21)/23701+(186238 m22)/118505-(126102 m23)/118505-(178233 m31)/118505-(185338 m32)/118505+(141088 m33)/118505 == 1.

Out[73]= {357.420000, Null}
```

Here are the solutions in this instance.

```
In[74]:= solns // N

Out[74]= {{m11 -> -2.22241, m12 -> 0., m13 -> -2.41203, 
  m21 -> -0.539924, m22 -> 2.33146*10^-172, m23 -> -0.585993, 
  m31 -> 0.921382, m32 -> -4.05984*10^-172, 
  m33 -> 1.}, {m11 -> -2.22241, m12 -> 0., m13 -> -2.41203, 
  m21 -> -0.539924, m22 -> 2.33146*10^-172, m23 -> -0.585993, 
  m31 -> 0.921382, m32 -> -4.05984*10^-172, 
  m33 -> 1.}, {m11 -> -2.22241, m12 -> 0., m13 -> -2.41203, 
  m21 -> -0.539924, m22 -> 2.33146*10^-172, m23 -> -0.585993, 
  m31 -> 0.921382, m32 -> -4.05984*10^-172, 
  m33 -> 1.}, {m11 -> -0.029351, m12 -> 0., m13 -> 0.409304, 
  m21 -> 0.0182228, m22 -> -2.19075*10^-169, m23 -> -0.25412, 
  m31 -> -0.0717095, m32 -> 2.05529*10^-169, 
  m33 -> 1.}, {m11 -> -0.029351, m12 -> 0., m13 -> 0.409304, 
  m21 -> 0.0182228, m22 -> -2.19075*10^-169, m23 -> -0.25412, 
  m31 -> -0.0717095, m32 -> 2.05529*10^-169, 
  m33 -> 1.}, {m11 -> -0.029351, m12 -> 0., m13 -> 0.409304, 
  m21 -> 0.0182228, m22 -> -2.19075*10^-169, m23 -> -0.25412, 
  m31 -> -0.0717095, m32 -> 2.05529*10^-169, 
  m33 -> 1.}, {m11 -> 0.541883, m12 -> 0., m13 -> -0.123031, 
  m21 -> -4.58369, m22 -> -5.60174*10^-170, m23 -> 1.0407, 
  m31 -> -4.40445, m32 -> -5.32622*10^-170, 
  m33 -> 1.}, {m11 -> 0.541883, m12 -> 0., m13 -> -0.123031, 
  m21 -> -4.58369, m22 -> -5.60174*10^-170, m23 -> 1.0407, 
  m31 -> -4.40445, m32 -> -5.32622*10^-170, 
  m33 -> 1.}, {m11 -> 0.541883, m12 -> 0., m13 -> -0.123031, 
  m21 -> -4.58369, m22 -> -5.60174*10^-170, m23 -> 1.0407, 
  m31 -> -4.40445, m32 -> -5.32622*10^-170, m33 -> 1.}}
```

We check that they satisfy the original expressions with very small numeric residuals.

```
In[76]:= exprs /. substitutions /. solns

Out[76]= {{-4.44089*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, -8.88178*10^-16, 0., 
  0., -1.11022*10^-16, -4.44089*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, 
  0.}, {-4.44089*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, -8.88178*10^-16, 0., 
  0., -1.11022*10^-16, -4.44089*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, 
  0.}, {-4.44089*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, -8.88178*10^-16, 0., 
  0., -1.11022*10^-16, -4.44089*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, 
  0.}, {-2.22045*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, -1.66533*10^-16, 
  1.11022*10^-16, -5.55112*10^-17, 1.11022*10^-16, -1.11022*10^-16, 
  5.55112*10^-17, 0.}, {-2.22045*10^-16, 
  1.11022*10^-16, -1.66533*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, -5.55112*10^-17, 
  1.11022*10^-16, -1.11022*10^-16, 5.55112*10^-17, 
  0.}, {-2.22045*10^-16, 1.11022*10^-16, -1.66533*10^-16, 
  1.11022*10^-16, -5.55112*10^-17, 1.11022*10^-16, -1.11022*10^-16, 
  5.55112*10^-17, 0.}, {2.34535*10^-15, -1.11022*10^-15, 
  1.11022*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16, 1.31839*10^-15, -1.11022*10^-15, 
  1.249*10^-15, -6.66134*10^-16, 
  0.}, {2.34535*10^-15, -1.11022*10^-15, 1.11022*10^-16, 
  2.22045*10^-16, 1.31839*10^-15, -1.11022*10^-15, 
  1.249*10^-15, -6.66134*10^-16, 
  0.}, {2.34535*10^-15, -1.11022*10^-15, 1.11022*10^-16, 
  2.22045*10^-16, 1.31839*10^-15, -1.11022*10^-15, 
  1.249*10^-15, -6.66134*10^-16, 0.}}
```

Comment: excuse me, i can't understand it.Please tell me at least how technic that you use called?
Also I can give real numbers for a(i,j) b(i,j), so we can test solution.
And here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177075/solve-non-linear-system-of-equation-in-mathematica
people say that this non-linear equation can be solved in 3D space as matrix equation, maybe it will be simpler to solve it in this way?

Comment: for example
A matrix
(0 -1 300
1 0 0
0 0 1)
B matrix
(-0.4009 -1.0787 446.1463
1.6180 0.8875 -159.2272
0.0003 0.0029 1)

but it can be a problem that matrix B was finded with some error.

Comment: My suggestion based on the math.stackexchange response would be to try to reframe this as a matrix null space computation. Using a nonzero tolerance you might be able to work past small numerical error in the input parameters.

Comment: can you be more specific? how matrix null space can help me?

Comment: If you have a matrix eqn of the form A.M = M.B with A, B known and M a matrix of unknowns, then A.M-M.B = 0 and this can be reformulated as a matrix-times-vector = 0, hence a null space computation.

Comment: I find out that there is to method to test if non-trivial solution exist `NullSpace[KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n], A]-KroneckerProduct[B, IdentityMatrix[n]]]` and `resultant(det(A−λE),det(B−λE),λ)=0`  but it seems mathematica give the trivial solution for this test method if I put matrices with parameters.